# knockout-jqueryui syntax to bind dialog position property

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have a client side object model that should restore the location of an arbitrary set of jquery UI dialogs. I've used the knockout-jqueryui library (located at: http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/dialog.html) with the following syntax:

```
<div class="documentWindow" data-bind="dialog: {resizable: true, title: windowTitle, width: width, height: height, position: windowPosition }">
```

In my model, I have properties for x and y, plus a computed property for the jquery position (which by the way, I think is neat, but is over-complicated to the point of uselessness for what I'm doing here, which is absolute positioning within a container). Here's the code that returns the windowPosition value:

```
self.x = ko.observable(data.x);
self.y = ko.observable(data.y);

self.windowPosition = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        var ret = { my: 'left top', at: self.x() + 'px ' + self.y() + 'px', of: '#dashboard' };
        return ret;
    },
    write: function(newVal) {
        //Do something here in a minute.
    }
});
```

I've hardcoded two of the view objects with different coordinates, but I can't get this goofy object to act properly. Is there some special syntax to tell this thing to put the upper left corner at x, y off of the upper left corner of the containing element (assuming the container is hardcoded, at the moment)? I've also tried:

```
return { my: 'left+' + self.x() + ' top+' + self.y(), at: 'left top', of: '#dashboard' };
```

and

```
return { my: 'left-' + self.x() + ' top-' + self.y(), at: 'left top', of: '#dashboard' };
```

with no better results.

Is there not a way to just specify this inline without all the crazy position stuff?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? Are you saying that the dialog is not positioning at all?

Comment: I think honestly the main problem is working with the jQuery UI position bits. The rest is probably simple. If I can figure out what string to use to tell it to position something at, say, 100, 50 from the upper left corner, then the knockout bits are easy, I think.

Comment: I filed a bug report, and the author is looking into adding that functionality. So, for once it turned out not to be something I was doing wrong.

https://github.com/gvas/knockout-jqueryui/issues/34#issuecomment-40575773